# javascript object System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In MVC, is it possible to pass an array of string `(List<string>)` from C# code to viewdata and then retrieve the value in the view? e.g:

***C#:***

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
names.Add("a");
names.Add("b");
ViewData["names"] = names;
```

***MVC view:***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var nameList = '<%= ViewData["names"] %>';
</script>
```

the code above runs OK but the returned javascript object in the view is "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" which cannot be parsed to get the values out.

What is the right way to achieve that rather than build the string with delimiter in C# and split the value in the view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) to generate the JS representation of your data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var nameList = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewData["names"]) %>;
</script>
```

Comment: good one! but the value return is now: "[a","b]" which is a string, not an array of string?

Comment: FTFY - You don't need the single quotes around the beestrings <%= %>

Comment: That was a pretty cool solution indeed. It should render as an array if you remove the outer quotes as in: var nameList = <%= new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewData["names"]) %>;